# How to Read .odt Document in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a file Upload control to Browse the .odt document and read that document By using Button. Please can anyone suggest me to how to do this Please any one give any idea to me.

Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. Do you want to upload a `.odt` document or read its content? Please take a look at [ask]

Comment: What i need is  upload .odt document and also read that .odt document content in a string  can you give me any idea to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [ODF.NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/odf/) API for this task.

For example to read and count the words in an *.odt document, you can do it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Independentsoft.Office.Odf;

namespace Sample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int wordCount = 0;
        string[] separator = new string[] { " " };

        TextDocument doc = new TextDocument("c:\\test\\input.odt");

        IList<Text> texts = doc.GetTexts();

        for (int i = 0; i < texts.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] words = texts[i].Value.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            wordCount += words.Length;
        }

        IList<Paragraph> paragraphs = doc.GetParagraphs();

        int emptyParagraphCount = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < paragraphs.Count; j++)
        {
            if(paragraphs[j].Content.Count == 0)
            {
                emptyParagraphCount++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Paragraphs=" + paragraphs.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Empty paragraphs=" + emptyParagraphCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Words=" + wordCount);

        Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

For more examples, please check these [tutorials](http://www.independentsoft.de/odf/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for give me help but where can i found dll's for using Independentsoft.Office.Odf; i am getting error can you give Provide me

Comment: I have a code for reading odt document but i am able to read one or two lines document not large document cannot read it will dispaly the symboles can you please hlep me to read large number of lines of document. i tried code is:    protected void btnread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              string text;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@".odt file path", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }   can you please help me out.